# Just the First Metabox what saves the data!

Tags: custom-post-types, php, metabox

I have a problem with meta boxes that I working on! I'm making a small meta box framework for my theme but I got a weird problem that is the first meta box **the first array**  it's the only one saves data!

I noticed something else may help I have 2 custom post types if I create the whole 2 meta boxes in one post type them both working but if I create a meta box for each post type only the first one what working and saves the data! I think the problem ( not sure ) that I did something wrong with nonce function.

There's my code:

```
function classy_create_meta_boxes( $args = array() ) {
$defaults = array(
    'id'        => 'default_field',                     // the ID of the setting in our options array, and the ID of the HTML form element
    'title'     => 'Default Title',                     // the label for the HTML form element
    'context'   => 'side',                              // the section this setting belongs to — must match the array key of a section in classy_options_page_sections()
    'callback'  => 'default',
    'priority'  => '',
    'screen'    => '',
    'options'   =>
        array(
            array(
                'id'    => '',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'key'   => '',
                'single'=> 'true',
                'std'   => '',
                'class' => 'regular-text',
                'desc'  => 'This is a default description'
            )
        )
);

// "extract" to be able to use the array keys as variables in our function output below
extract( wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ) );

// additional arguments for use in form field output in the function classy_form_field_fn!
$field_args = array(
    'id'        => $id,
    'callback'  => $callback,
    'priority'  => $priority,
    'context'   => $context,
    'screen'    => $screen,
    'options'   => $options
);

add_meta_box(
    $id,
    $title,
    'classy_portfolio_gallery_callback',
    $screen,
    $context,
    $priority,
    $field_args
);}

function classy_metaboxes_options(  ) {
$prefix = "classy_";


$metaboxes[] = array(
    'id'        => $prefix.'messages_email_details_meta_box',
    'title'     => 'Email',
    'screen'    => 'messages',
    'context'   => 'side',
    'priority'  => 'default',
    'options'   => array(
        array(
            'id'        => 'form_full_name',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'label'     => 'Full Name',
            'desc'      => 'This is a default description',
            'single'    => true,
        ),

        array(
            'id'        => 'form_email',
            'type'      => 'email',
            'label'     => 'Email',
            'desc'      => 'This is a default description',
            'single'    => true,
        ),
    )
);

$metaboxes[] = array(
    'id'        => $prefix.'portfolio_gallery_meta_box',
    'title'     => 'Gallery',
    'screen'    => 'portfolio',
    'context'   => 'normal',
    'priority'  => 'default',
    'options'   => array(
        array(
            'id'        => 'gallery_meta_box',
            'key'       => '_gallery',
            'single'    => true,
            'type'      => 'gallery'
        )
    )
);

return $metaboxes;}

function classy_add_meta_box() {

if (!empty( classy_metaboxes_options() )) {
    foreach (classy_metaboxes_options() as $option ) {
        classy_create_meta_boxes($option);
    }
}}

function classy_portfolio_gallery_callback( $post, $metaboxes ) {
global $post;
$fields = $metaboxes['args']['options'];

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    switch ($field['type']) {
        case "gallery":
            // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
            $html = '<input type="hidden" name="'. $field['id'].'_nonce' .'" id="'. $field['id'].'_nonce' .'" value="' .wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ). '" />';

            // Get the gallery data if its already been entered
            $gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_classy_'.$field['id'], $field['single']);

            if (empty($gallery))
                $html .= '<a href="#" id="classy_portfolio_gallery_upload">Set gallery images</a><br>';
            else
                $html .= '<a href="#" id="classy_portfolio_gallery_upload">Update gallery images</a><br>';

            $html .= "<input type='hidden' id='classy_portfolio_gallery' name='_classy_{$field['id']}' value='{$gallery}'>";


            $html .= '<div class="classy_images">';
            $gallery_images = explode('|', $gallery);
            $gallery_images = array_filter($gallery_images, function($value) { return $value !== ''; });

            foreach ($gallery_images as $image)
                $html .= '<img height="70" style="display: inline-block" src="'.$image.'" >';
            $html .= "</div>";

            $html .= "<div class='remove-link'></div>";
            break;

        case "text":
        case "email":
            // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
            $html = '<input type="hidden" name="'.$field['id'].'_nonce'.'" id="'.$field['id'].'_nonce'.'" value="' .wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ). '" />';
            $val = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_classy_'.$field['id'], $field['single']);
            //print_r($val);
            $html .= "<label for='{$field['id']}' class='description'> {$field['label']}: </label><br>";
            $html .= "<input type='{$field['type']}' style='width: 100%; max-width: 100%' id='{$field['id']}' name='_classy_{$field['id']}' value='{$val}'><br>";
            $html .= "<span class='description'> {$field['desc']} </span><br>";
            break;
    }

    echo $html;
}}
function classy_save_portfolio_gallery_meta_box($post_id, $post) {

foreach (classy_metaboxes_options() as $option) {

    foreach ($option['options'] as $field) {

        // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
        // because save_post can be triggered at other times
        if ( !isset($_POST[$field['id'].'_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST[$field['id'].'_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
            return $post->ID;
        }

        // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
        // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

        $events_meta['_classy_'.$field['id']] = $_POST['_classy_'.$field['id']];

        // Add values of $events_meta as custom fields

        foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
            if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
            $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
            if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
                update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
                add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            }
            if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
        }

    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the wrong part is looping the **wp_create_nonce()** inside function **classy_portfolio_gallery_callback** I just get it outside the loop and put a fixed name and edit also the save function **classy_save_portfolio_gallery_meta_box** for specfic the first condition with the new name attr.